# Qt 5 C++ HTTP POST issues

Tags: c++, http-post, qt5

I have been trying to use C++ and Qt for a HTTP POST request and after very much research this is the only way I could get the program to even compile. 95% of the examples had plenty of errors and wanted libraries that no longer exist. The issue is that when I do use this code its "reply" equals null... Is there any better way to do a HTTP POST request, and what am I doing wrong?

```
QEventLoop eventLoop;
QUrl myURL(QString("http://example.com/"));
QNetworkRequest request(myURL);
QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
QObject::connect(&mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));

QUrlQuery qu;
qu.addQueryItem("unm", aUser);
qu.addQueryItem("pwd", aPass);
QUrl params;
params.setQuery(qu);
QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.post(request, params.toEncoded());
qDebug() << "Success" <<reply->readAll();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to execute the event loop before reading the reply. Qt documentation says

> `QNetworkAccessManager` has an asynchronous API.

So you have to wait till the reply is finished. That is the purpose of using an `QEventLoop`. you need to block the calling thread until `QNetworkAccessManager` emits `finished(QNetworkReply*)`.
Everything is fine in your code, except you do not execute the `QEventLoop`. 
Put `eventLoop.exec()` after sending the request.

```
QUrl myURL(QString("http://example.com"));
QNetworkRequest request(myURL);
QNetworkAccessManager mgr;

QUrlQuery qu;
qu.addQueryItem("unm", aUser);
qu.addQueryItem("pwd", aPass);
QUrl params;
params.setQuery(qu);
QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.post(request, params.toEncoded());


QEventLoop eventLoop;
QObject::connect(&mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
eventLoop.exec();

qDebug() << "Success" <<reply->readAll();
```

Comment: This did help a lot, It still is having some problems though. Using wireshark it seems to be doing a HTTP-GET instead of a HTTP-POST. Any ideas why this may be?